# Como girar un mapa de bit por el centro

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy intentando girar una imagen, por el centro del mapa de bits.

E encontrado esto : `imgviewD.setRotation(180);`, pero no lo hace girar.

No quiero usar Matrix por que es de API30 y mi app va desde la API 23.

De que otra forma puedo girar la imagen por el centro, 180 grados (por codigo), por que la necesito guardar girada.

Answer (score 1):

Mira la [referencia de la clase Matrix](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix#postRotate(float)), claramente dice:

> Added in API level 1

Puedes hacerlo así:

```
public Bitmap rotate180(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(180f);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```

Comment: Pero Matrix es de API 30, y eso me dara conflicto en APIs menores a la 30

Comment: @JUANMIGUELDIAZHERNANDEZ seguro? Ya probaste y te dió error?

Comment: No e echo el intento de probarlo, pero creo que si daria error, supongo .... o estoy equivocado ?

Comment: por qué crees que es API 30? Mira la referencia por favor, es API 1.